# xamarin android player resolution

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-android-player

I have some problem with XAP resolution: as you can see in the attached image the resolution is so poor that is not possible to read the text.
I triyed to put the maximun scale (Player -> Scale -> 100%) but it haven't solved the problem.
Could you help me?
Thank you.

Xamarin Android Player 0.6.5 (1)
OSX El Capitan vers. 10.11.6
[Compare the resolution in Xamarin Android Player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkFhZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin Android Player was deprecated some time ago, so it wouldn't be advisable to continue using it as it won't be updated any more. It did not graduate from a Preview product, so the final release likely contains some bugs still.

A better option would be to use Google's own AVD - making sure to enable HAXM acceleration to speed them up. Using the x86 images with HAXM is just as fast as VirtualBox, plus you have the advantage of being able to use any API level that Google publishes an image for (going forward Xamarin Android Player will not receive any new images).

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/android-sdk-emulator/

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/accelerating_android_emulators/

Comment: Thank you. Now I'm testing Genymotion and it is working prety good.